# Django: force reload file to update values

Tags: python, django, file, caching, django-1.7

I have a file where I store 4 bits (for exemple "0100"), the three first corresponds to sensors status. I want to read this values; it works but just once: when I change values, when I show these values in templates they aren't updated. I have to restart the server to get updated value, so I suppose this is a cache error. My code to get sensors status (if you want other code like my view or other ask me):

```
def get_sensor(s):
    if s is not None:
        if s == "open":
            if s_open == 1:
                return True
            else:
                return False

        elif s == "close":
            if s_close == 1:
                return True
            else:
                return False

        elif s == "ir":
            if s_ir == 1:
                return True
            else:
                return False
```

My code to read values (this code works, I use it in another part of my code):

```
with open(data_file_path, "rb") as ft:
    f = pickle.load(ft)
s_open = f[0]
s_close = f[1]
s_ir = f[2]
```

So how can I update the values from file? If I have to clear or disable cache it's not important, it's for a small programm.

Thanks, and sorry for my English I'm French.

Comment: How are you closing and reopening the file?

Comment: As you can see in my code I use pickle with the "with" syntax:
with open(data_file_path, "rb") as ft: f = pickle.load(ft)

Comment: Close the file at the end of your reading, ft.closed

Comment: No even if I close file manually (but with the "with" syntax we don't have to do it) it doesn't work. I precise I edit file manually, no by a Django page, so maybe Django not detect the file has changed?

Comment: How do you update the value in the file? Is the value updated before you try to read the updated value from the file?

Comment: I update manually with a file editor because in the final project the file will be updated by an external programm. Of course I update the file before reading it. ^^ And I can refresh the page as I want, while I don't edit any file of my site or restart server, values are not updated.

Comment: Where is the code where you open the file? Is it inside a view?

Comment: I have this architecture:
- view
-- model (view load model)
--- portal.py (model load file "portal.py") -> I open the file here